# Theory of Poker vs Theory of Poker Applied to NL

Tags: texas-hold-em, nlhe, books

I am a beginner poker player who just started NLHE at the small/micro stakes.  I was looking online for beginner books and saw several recommendations for The Theory of Poker by David Sklansky to be a first read.

Looking to buy it, I saw that there was a newer book that specifically applies to NLHE.  I also read some reviews though that this book is less like a remastered and more like a companion book.

For anyone who has read both, which would you recommend?

Thanks, I would also not mind other beginner poker book recommendations

Comment: Both books and many more as you develop..

Comment: As Jon said, both and many more. I know they are dated now, but Harrington on Hold'em  is a great introduction for new players, especially to tournament poker fundamentals. I believe he has a newer one now. Jonathan Little writes good poker books too.